# Concat a value from a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list with values:

```
list1 = ['823917583038', '107002622040', '118511252091', ]
```

i wan to to concat every element inside the list and have a result like this:

```
print(result)
Result : result[0] '8 23917583 03 8',
Result : result[1] '1 07002622 04 0',
Result : result[2] '1 18511252 09 1',
```

Any better suggetions?

Code :

```
list1 = ['823917583038', '107002622040', '118511252091', ] 
li = list1[0]
l4 = "'" + li[0:1] + " " + li[1:9] + " " + li[9:11] + " " + li[-1:] + "'" + ","
print(l4)
```

Edited.
Thank you.

Comment: can you include your desired output?

Comment: You'll need to loop over `list1`, instead of just grabbing its 1st element (`list1[0]`).

Comment: Look up how to do string formatting, especially f-strings.  However, if you have a consistent slicing format, perhaps a simple expression or function to format your elements is the best way to go.

Comment: "Can't really solve this, any suggetions?" I don't understand. How is what the code does, different from what you want it to do?

Comment: just do `"'" + ' '.join(li) + "'"`

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question, then this should work for you

```
l4 = [i[0:1]+' ' + i[1:9] + ' ' + i[9:11] + ' ' + i[-1:] for i in list1]

print(l4)
```